# Should I manually validate parameters in TypeScirpt if create the library?

Tags: typescript, validation, typechecking

Knowing at least cursorily how TypeScript works, everyone can answer: "Yes. The TypeScript is just transpiling the code to JavaScript but not adding any extra behavior including the type checking during execution." For example,

```js
function example(parameter: string): void {
  console.log(parameter.charAt(1));
}
```

will be transpiled to:

```js
"use strict";
function example(parameter) {
  console.log(parameter.charAt(1));
}
```

And if JavaScript user will call `example(3)`, the error `Uncaught TypeError: parameter.charAt is not a function` will be thrown.

Well, if I understand this why I as asking this question? Because I am about to spend a tens of hours for improvement of my library [(@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/README.md)), but, more importantly, increase the library size **by multiple times**. It is not the exaggeration. For example, for the version 1.6.x,  the [addElementsToArray](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/Documentation/Arrays/addElementsToArray/addElementsToArray.md) function is pretty simple and have no dependencies:

```js
export default function addElementsToArray<ArrayElement>(
  namedParameters:
    {
      targetArray: Array<ArrayElement>;
      newElements: Array<ArrayElement>;
      mutably: boolean;
    } &
    (
      { toStart: true; } |
      { toEnd: true; } |
      { toPosition__numerationFrom0: number; } |
      { toPosition__numerationFrom1: number; }
    )
): Array<ArrayElement> {

  const workpiece: Array<ArrayElement> = namedParameters.mutably ?
      namedParameters.targetArray : [ ...namedParameters.targetArray ];

  if ("toStart" in namedParameters) {
    workpiece.unshift(...namedParameters.newElements);
    return workpiece;
  }


  if ("toEnd" in namedParameters) {
    workpiece.push(...namedParameters.newElements);
    return workpiece;
  }


  const positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0: number = "toPosition__numerationFrom0" in namedParameters ?
      namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom0 : namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom1 - 1;

  workpiece.splice(positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0, 0, ...namedParameters.newElements);

  return workpiece;
}
```

Once I have improved it with type checking, it has become to:

```js
import Logger from "../Logging/Logger";
import InvalidParameterValueError from "../Errors/InvalidParameterValue/InvalidParameterValueError";
import IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameterError from
    "../Errors/IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameter/IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameterError";
import stringifyAndFormatArbitraryValue from "../Strings/stringifyAndFormatArbitraryValue";
import isArbitraryObject from "../TypeGuards/Objects/isArbitraryObject";
import isNotUndefined from "../TypeGuards/Nullables/isNotUndefined";
import isNonNegativeInteger from "../TypeGuards/Numbers/isNonNegativeInteger";
import isNaturalNumber from "../TypeGuards/Numbers/isNaturalNumber";


export default function addElementsToArray<ArrayElement>(
  namedParameters:
      Readonly<
        (
          {
            mutably: true;
            targetArray: Array<ArrayElement>;
          } |
          {
            mutably: false;
            targetArray: ReadonlyArray<ArrayElement>;
          }
        ) &
        {
          newElements: ReadonlyArray<ArrayElement>;
          toStart?: true;
          toEnd?: true;
          toPosition__numerationFrom0?: number;
          toPosition__numerationFrom1?: number;
        }
      >
): Array<ArrayElement> {

  if (!isArbitraryObject(namedParameters)) {
    Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
      errorInstance: new InvalidParameterValueError({
        parameterNumber: 1,
        parameterName: "namedParameters",
        messageSpecificPart: "The first and only parameter of 'addElementsToArray' must be of the object type."
      }),
      title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
      occurrenceLocation: "addElementsToArray(namedParameters)"
    });
  }


  if (!Array.isArray(namedParameters.targetArray)) {
    Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
      errorInstance: new InvalidParameterValueError({
        parameterName: "namedParameters",
        parameterNumber: 1,
        messageSpecificPart: "The 'targetArray' is not the valid array and has value:\n" +
            `${ stringifyAndFormatArbitraryValue(namedParameters.targetArray) }`
      }),
      title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
      occurrenceLocation: "addElementsToArray(namedParameters)"
    });
  }


  const alternativelyRequestOptions: Array<true | number> = [
    namedParameters.toStart,
    namedParameters.toEnd,
    namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom0,
    namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom1
  ].filter(isNotUndefined);

  if (alternativelyRequestOptions.length > 1) {

    Logger.logError({
      errorType: IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameterError.NAME,
      title: IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameterError.localization.defaultTitle,
      description: "Exactly one of 'toStart', 'toEnd', 'toPosition__numerationFrom0', 'toPosition__numerationFrom1' " +
          "must be specified while actually multiple of them has been. No elements will be added to target array.",
      occurrenceLocation: "addElementsToArray(namedParameters)"
    });

    return namedParameters.targetArray;

  }


  const workpiece: Array<ArrayElement> = namedParameters.mutably ?
      namedParameters.targetArray : [ ...namedParameters.targetArray ];

  if (namedParameters.toStart === true) {
    workpiece.unshift(...namedParameters.newElements);
    return workpiece;
  }


  if (namedParameters.toEnd === true) {
    workpiece.push(...namedParameters.newElements);
    return workpiece;
  }


  let positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0: number;

  if (isNonNegativeInteger(namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom0)) {
    positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0 = namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom0;
  } else if (isNaturalNumber(namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom1)) {
    positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0 = namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom1 - 1;
  } else {

    Logger.logError({
      errorType: InvalidParameterValueError.NAME,
      title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
      description: alternativelyRequestOptions.length === 0 ?
          "None one of 'toStart', 'toEnd', 'toPosition__numerationFrom0', 'toPosition__numerationFrom1' has been specified." :
          (
            "The specified value of 'toStart', 'toEnd', 'toPosition__numerationFrom0' or 'toPosition__numerationFrom1' has " +
            "invalid type, value or numbers set."
          ) +
          "No elements will be added to target array.",
      occurrenceLocation: "addElementsToArray(namedParameters)"
    });

    return namedParameters.targetArray;

  }


  workpiece.splice(positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0, 0, ...namedParameters.newElements);

  return workpiece;

}
```

In this case, the validation takes about half of the lines and also a lot of dependencies has appeared. Sometimes, the validation could than 90% of function lines. The library distributable will become much heavier by multiple types which is critical for the front-end application where each kilobyte is on count.

The above checks are not meticulous yet! Additionally, we can:

- When the alternatively required named parameters (`toStart`, `toEnd`, `toPosition__numerationFrom0`, `toPosition__numerationFrom1`) are more than 1, check which of them exactly has been passed and log their names.
- Split the checks for the types of these parameters and the check does none of these parameters has been passed (currently these two checks are being performed at the same time)
- If above parameters has incorrect subtype (for example, if `toStart` or `toEnd` has `false` value or `toPosition__numerationFrom0` or `toPosition__numerationFrom1` are negative or fractional numbers), log this separately.

### Potential falsy issues

In short, I could be reported by non-TypeScript users about bugs caused by invalid parameter's type, however if the same code has been written by the TypeScript, the TypeScript has emitted the error. Ever finally it will  become clear that the issue was because of invalid parameter type in the combination with JavaScript usage instead of TypeScript, the time will be wasted by the investigations, conversations, etc. Also it could be the huge number of such issues which actually just the invalid TypeScript.

### The update to the occasion of bounty

This question already has been answered, but the potential future increasing of the size of my libraries by multiple times because of parameters validation is bugging me. To exhaust this question, I need to be told either "You are doing the right thing, keep on it! The increasing of the distributive's size by the multiple time does not matter ever for the frontend application if it because of parameters validation." or "The large size of helper library is not good ever if it because of parameter's validation. You should skip the parameters validation to keep the library slim." by senior/master web developers.

Comment: You can either perform the validations, or you can expect that everyone using the library will be using it in a type-aware manner. (I fully expect libraries I use to break if I use call signatures different from what the library's docs say - and that's *my* fault, not the library's, IMO)

Comment: I mean, it's not just in TypeScript. If you wrote it with JavaScript you would have to do the same validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good and common practice to do validation at the customer-facing edge of your system.

All that throat-clearing code at the start can be seen as a good thing, making the bodies of those functions more simple and confidently written.

You can also certainly shrink the code by either finding or building an assertion library.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are conflating two separate issues here. On the one hand you have the *typing* of interfaces which the user is accessing (e.g. function signatures), which allows a TypeScript client to verify that function calls are being done with appropriate values and is required for a module to play nicely with TypeScript projects. On the other hand you have *validation* of interfaces, where you do programmatic checks of each input to make sure it has an appropriate type and value.

**Generally one of the big advantages of TypeScript is that these programmatic checks are not necessary.**

I would caution against verifying every input, the way you do in your example. There is no guarantee that you will always block every non-allowed value, and in situations where 'every kilobyte counts' you also want to avoid making a lot of checks which are probably not necessary everywhere. Many of the users of this module will be validating their data before it is passed to your code, in the case of user inputs.

Furthermore, longer and more complex code will be harder to maintain and slower to add new features to. It is more likely to develop bugs as well. There may be a few places where allowing invalid values through could cause serious damage, and adding checks to those places *specifically* is good practice, but if someone passes bad arguments to a list manipulation function and then gets an error, it's not the end of the world.

Your time may be better spent on writing good documentation for those who use your module with JavaScript. As an added advantage this documentation also helps TypeScript users.